# How to implement a DIAL launch on Android TVs and Google TVs?

Tags: google-cast, android-tv, google-tv, netflix, app-launcher

Since we are struggling to get support for this (we tried Google Developer Support and the DIAL "Contact Us" Google Forms: http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/contact-us) I writing here in hope that someone from the community can help us.

We are trying to implement the DIAL launch of our receiver app on Android TVs and Google TVs using DIAL. The app is already published on the Google Play Store.

So far we didn't find any specific documentation on how to do this in Android TVs/Google TVs, the only specific tutorial close to what we want was for Amazon Fire TV (which we followed and worked in our Fire TV Stick): https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/dial-integration.html

But this configuration from Amazon doesn't work with our Android app installed on Google TV (we are testing with a Chromecast with Google TV HD and Mi Stick with Android TV devices), only on Fire TV. As explained, we didn't find any specific tutorial or documentation to launch apps with DIAL on Android TVs and Google TVs anywhere. But we did noticed that the Netlix app is launchable by a simple POST request in both Google TV and Fire TV. We only achived this behaviour in the Fire TV (as mentioned). We already registered the app on the DIAL registries: http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/dial-registry/namespace-database

How we can make this work the same way the Netflix app works in the Google and Android TVs?

Below a summary of what works and what not:

```
1) POST /apps/Netflix --> works on Fire TV
2) POST /apps/io.mythreal.unityreceiver --> works on Fire TV
3) POST /apps/Netflix --> works on Google TV and Android TV
4) POST /apps/io.mythreal.unityreceiver --> DOES NOT work on Google TV and Android TV
```

Basically, we want to make 4) work. Can you help us to configure this? We suspect we need some additional configuration in the AndroidManfest.xml file like we did for the Fire TV.

Here is a video showing what is the problem we are facing, I hope this clarifies any doubts: https://youtu.be/5UTU2fbFxqg